# Convert WebHeaderCollection to NameValueCollection in .Net Core

Tags: http-headers, .net-core, namevaluecollection

Before of dotNetCore (.Net Core), `WebHeaderCollection` was inherit from `NameValueCollection`, but not now.

And I need to convert `WebHeaderCollection` (`HttpWebResponse.Headers`) to the type property `NameValueCollection`.

Has anyone ever had to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the collection iterating the keys, for example:

```
var nvCollection = new NameValueCollection(whCollection.Count)
foreach (var key in whCollection)
{
    nvCollection.Add(key, whCollection[key]);
}
return nvCollection;
```

Unfortunately, current object hierarchy doesn't allow more generic way to achieve this by LINQ or constructor initilization.